# How to make a Publisher that sends multiple values in Combine

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

Could you help me with a Combine issue?

I'd like to make a Publisher which sends multiple values during its lifetime. In more detail, I want to wrap a method with a completion handler into a Publisher, and the completion handler is supposed to be called multiple times. For example, it's a method used for receiving messages via WebSocket like this:

```swift
webSocketClient.receiveMessage { message, error in
    // this closure is called multiple times, everytime a message comes
    ...
}
```

How can I wrap this into a Publisher? I want something like `AnyPublisher<String, Error>` in the end.

Wrapping these is super easy when I use other FRP libraries. For example, in ReactiveSwift, it can be achieved by using [`SignalProducer.init(_ startHandler:)`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift/blob/master/Sources/SignalProducer.swift#L68-L79). In RxSwift, it's [`Observable.create`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxSwift/Observables/Create.swift#L20) method.

In Combine, I found `Future` can be used when there's only one value to emit, but it doesn't suit my current case. I couldn't find any initializer for Publisher for this use case.

Also, I found [Effect.run](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture/blob/main/Sources/ComposableArchitecture/Effect.swift#L179-L183) in TCA (The Composable Architecture) which can be used for this case. It seems custom publishers are used in its implementation, which seems a bit complicated for simple usage, but is this the only way? Are there any other easy ways to achieve the similar behavior?

I feel this is a quite common scenario, so I'd like to know how Combine users are handling this case in practice.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are two options.

- In a SwiftUI environment make the class which contains the code conform to `ObservableObject` and add a `@Published` property

  ```
  class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
        @Published var message = ""

        func loadData() {
            webSocketClient.receiveMessage { message, error in
                self.message = message
                ...
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  In the view create a `@StateObject` of the view model to be notified about new messages.
- Or declare a subject to `send` values

  ```
  class ViewModel {
        let subject = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()

        func loadData() {
            webSocketClient.receiveMessage { message, error in
                self.subject.send(message)
                ...
            }
        }
    }
  ```

  To receive the notifications get an instance of the class, call `sink` on the subject and store the result into a strong reference.

Comment: I see. I can understand that it's possible by introducing a Subject or other variables. However, is it possible without introducing them?

Comment: For example, in RxSwift, it's possible like this without introducing another variable. Isn't this possible in Combine?

```swift
let observable = Observable.create { observer in 
    webSocketClient.receiveMessage { message, error in 
        observer.on(.next(message))
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: `let observable =...` is also a variable.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. ```Observable.create {...}.subscribe { ... }``` is possible as well.